# Login loop when any Nvidia driver installed (ubuntu 16.04.3 , unity, lightdm)

Tags: unity, nvidia, lightdm, hybrid-graphics

**[temporarily resolved]** Almost every time the system updates, I need to reinstall the NVIDIA driver. But now it's in loop login with the NVIDIA driver installed.
I have installed the direct driver of the site and also by "apt" (any version) and none works.

When uninstalling the driver, it works normal.

I tried several tutorials!!

information:

Intel graphics / nvidia geforce 930M
Linux 4.4.0-96-generic

---

**Solution**

I formatted and soon deactivated the kernel update

sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic

then I installed the nvidia 384.69 driver from the site
I installed 304 (apt install nvidia-304) and re-installed 384.69 from the site

I do not know if it works with 384.90

** To go back**
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic

sorry for my English.

Comment: +1 confirmed similar problem. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 (But using 16.04 kernel (`linux-image-generic-lts-xenial` = `linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic`)

Answer (score 0):

I am using exactly the same hardware as OP, and I concluded that latest `nvidia-384` driver (version `384.69-0ubuntu0~gpu14.04.1`) from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` does not fit the latest `4.4.0-96` kernel.

So I just remove it to downgrade my system to `4.4.0-93`:

#### WARNING: destructive command, make sure you have another bootable kernel !

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.4.0-96 linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
```

Note that this may cause the kernel not updating anymore, so sometime after Nvidia fixing this I may decide to install back.

Related Post: [Why does nvidia driver 346 work while driver 384 doesn't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/955143/why-does-nvidia-driver-346-work-while-driver-384-doesnt)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Updating to the HWE kernel (4.10) seems to resolve it:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

Ubuntu 16.04.3 release ships with the updated kernel. Hence, a reinstall should also fix it.