# System is running in low graphics mode after partial software update in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg, lightdm

I did software update from the GUI pop-up notification - updated everything suggested except nvidia drivers (I had nvidia-375 installed, my GPU is nvidia Geforce 920M), and nvidia opencl libs.

After reboot it threw me that

> The system is running in low graphics mode

So as I thought nvidia drivers should be also updated (to 378, or 384), because Xorg would require fresh nvidia libs - I did remove the current nvidia driver, then installed newer ones (378 then 384) but that didn't changed anything ...

Restarting lightdm not showing unity log-in gui, instead in the terminal I'm getting this:

```
No suitable _DSM call found
```

(also was getting this error during each boot with nvidia-settings and nvidia-prime installed, and was NOT getting when these packages are not installed)

As an additional info I have a nouveau driver blacklisted as so in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist nouveau
```

Also in the `Xorg.0.log` I can see the following

```
Fatal server error:
    [26.673] (EE) no screens found(EE)
```

Is this issue related to lightdm???

What's the root of the problem?

How to fix this?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot at UEFI.

Comment: @MichaelBay its been disabled ...

Comment: What happens if you comment out `blacklist nouveau` in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Comment: @ElderGeek I commented it out, same thing happened, nothing changed

Comment: Mabny have found [this useful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau/481540#481540) perhaps you will as well. Unless of course it's a bug. Are you running bumblebee?

Comment: @ElderGeek Im not running bumblebee, was running nvidia-prime, but i uninstalled it to localize the issue

Comment: bumblebee has some related bugs called against it which is why I asked. Did you just remove the nvidia driver or did you purge it?

Comment: @ElderGeek yeah did I purge it, I ran this command - apt-get remove --purge nvidia*

Comment: The root of the problem is whatever non-Ubuntu packages caused the 'partial software update'. Solve that first, then complete the upgrade, then see if graphics drivers are still a problem at all.

Comment: Here is our attempt to fix this, https://askubuntu.com/questions/957392/login-loop-when-any-nvidia-driver-installed-ubuntu-16-04-3-unity-lightdm
Hmm, I find that this page is not search engine optimized